# Are the functions $f(x)g(x)$, $f(x)-g(x)$ and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ continuous when $x$ varies in a topological space?

Tags: continuity

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space and the functions:
$$f:X\to \Bbb R$$
$$g:X\to \Bbb R^+$$
be continuous. Are the functions $f(x)g(x)$, $f(x)-g(x)$ and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ continuous?

Comment: This has bean dealt with before. See here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215109/continuity-of-f-cdot-g-and-f-g-on-standard-topology/308013#308013

Comment: And you don't need positive values for $g$, but nonzero values is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because all these operations $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are *continuous*, and the mapping $X\to\Bbb R,\ \ x\mapsto (f(x),g(x))$ is continuous, too, and the *composition* of continuous functions is continuous, too.